# Ace editor: customizing syntax error gutter

Tags: ace-editor

Just wondering, if the syntax error gutter can be customized? Also is it possible to highlight texts which has syntax error?

For example below I am trying to check value of `myString` against string a "chetan" but without quotes. Now this is a syntax error. Currently we display the error in gutter prior to line number. But is it possible to customize the ace editor provide inline highlight and change the color?

```
if myString==chetan:
  //do something
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add underline similar to the way cloud9 and zed do (see https://github.com/zedapp/zed/commit/59ae66c545db2ad92dc5efc1a069edd16960ebdd) or modify highlighter tokens see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ace-discuss/_PRUJ_HemNo/wvDf9FqwzhMJ

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the line that has an error does not have spans, so I did the following:

```
if( editor.getValue() != "" && $('.ace_text-layer.ace_line:not(:has(span))')){
  $('.ace_line:not(:has(span))').css("background","#FCBEA5")
}else {
  $('.ace_line:not(:has(span))').css("background","#000000")
}
```

There are a few issues with this, such as it highlighting the current line.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the gutter you can play around its .ace_gutter properties.
Now suppose if you want to change the width of the gutter,

```
.ace_gutter > .ace_layer {
    width: 20px !important;
}
```

This will help you in changing the width of the gutter by overriding the present gutter width. Similarly, you can edit other properties too.