# Ace Editor - Remove error for specific syntax

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I'm trying to make ace editor not count the following as "improper syntax" and be used for templating. Currently, I haven't been able to find anything similar that helps me work with ace and edit this. The closest I've found is [Ace editor: customizing syntax error gutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284979/ace-editor-customizing-syntax-error-gutter) which didn't really point me in a direction?

I want it so ace doesn't interpret:

```
var derp = %{ (whatever can go in here) }%;
```

both %{ and %{ respectively as an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ace uses jshint for syntax checking which is not very extensible.
If you do not have a better syntax checker, you can try hooking into https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/mode/javascript_worker.js#L118
and replace `%{ ... }%` blocks with `expression/* ... */` like

```
value.replace(/%\{([^}]|}[^%])*}%/g, "window/*$1*/")
```

the expression is needed to keep js valid and comment to keep lines

Comment: Yes, basically since you are using different language, you need to create a new version of worker. You can also try opening an issue on github, in case they agree to add a hook for source transformation before passing it to jshint

Comment: This doesn't allow me to add custom code-coloring to this though, and seems to take away the comment code-coloring as well.

Comment: My answer was only about syntax checking, it doesn't affect coloring in any way. If you have some question about highlighting too, please update your question, or create a new one.

Comment: Thank you @auser ,I wanted something like this for html, this pointed me in the right direction